# Is it possible in Odoo to redirect to my module's view on my module's installation?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I have created a module called 'Ticket Booking' and I want to redirect to that module whenever it is installed or upgraded.

NB : I want similar functioning like what happens when we install website in Odoo.

I have tried to achieve it by modifying several JavaScript and Python hooks but i couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `todo` actions like in [website](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/website/views/website_views.xml#L558L562) module:

```
<record id="website_configurator_todo" model="ir.actions.todo">
    <field name="name">Start Website Configurator</field>
    <field name="action_id" ref="start_configurator_act_url"/>
    <field name="sequence">0</field>
</record>
```

Set a value of the `state` field to `open` to force Odoo to execute the action on module upgrade:

```
<field name="state">open</field>
```